# ms sql search by nvarchar field

Tags: search, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

I am using MS SQl 2012 and have simple table

```
id (int) - primary key
fullname (nvarchar(500) 
age (int)
…
```

In table over 15 millions records and I need make simple search like

```
select * from Customers where full name like '%sometext%'
```

Details:
1. It can have few words
2. There are used many languages
3. that fullname  doesn't have any indexes yet

What the best way make search like that? Which indexes I should add? Can I use full text search if there are not only english words?

Comment: Normal indexes won't help that kind of query. You need SQL Full Text Search or a separate tool like Apache Lucene.net.

Comment: On second thought, is the column for a person's full name? ``nvarchar(500)`` seems really big for that. You could split the full name into individual names and add them separately to a secondary table linked to the main table.

Answer (score 0):

[Sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) The above query does not meet the requirements therefore no index on your `full name` column is going to help. You will need to restructure your data or filter on something sargable first (age = 30) and then scan `full name`.

The other option is to pull in a text searching technology as @afrancis indicated.